# Retrieving the value of a property pom.xml

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I would like to retrieve the value of a property in file application.properties in my service layer of my application, the value of setVersion is null

```
version=5.4.3
```

and the function for recovery the version

```
@Override
public ProductDto getVersionApp() {
    ProductDto dto = new ProductDto();
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    try {
        prop.load(new FileInputStream("/concerto-rest-api/src/main/resources/application.properties"));

              dto.setVersion(prop.getProperty("version"));
              LOG.info("version ",prop.getProperty("version"));

    } catch (IOException ex) {}

    return dto;
}
```

Comment: you are trying to retrieve value set in pom and xml or application.properties. You should make it clear.

Comment: sorry, i try to retrieve value from file application.properties

Comment: edit your question and subject .. You don't need to read the file to get the value. You can use `@Value`

Comment: thanks it helped me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `@Value("${version}")` in you service, provided you service is a spring bean.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the spring-boot framework, there are several ways you can get that property.

**First:**

```
@SpringBootApplication  
public class SpringBoot01Application {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        ConfigurableApplicationContext  context=SpringApplication.run(SpringBoot01Application.class, args);  
        String str1=context.getEnvironment().getProperty("version");
        System.out.println(str1);  
    }  
}
```

**Second:**

```
@Component  
public class Student {  
    @Autowired  
    private Environment env;  
    public void speak() {  
        System.out.println("=========>" + env.getProperty("version"));  
    }  
}
```

**Third:**

```
@Component    
@PropertySource("classpath:jdbc.properties")//if is application.properties，then you don't need to write @PropertyScource("application.properties")    
public class Jdbc {    

    @Value("${jdbc.user}")  
    private String user;    

    @Value("${jdbc.password}")   
    private String password;    

    public void speack(){    
        System.out.println("username:"+user+"------"+"password:"+password);    
    }    

}
```